# how can i add image in the text area and when click on the button how can i add the same image

Tags: html

I have a textarea and add button.when i'm loading the page i want to place image in the textarea.And when click on the add button the same image will be added in the textarea.but i can't get.here is my code.

```
<div class="container" style="width:500px">
<div class="control-group" align="left" style="float: left" onselect="selectText()">
<textarea id="myTextarea" contenteditable="true" style="height: 200px; width: 300px" onclick="storeCaret(this);"
onselect="storeCaret(this);" onkeyup="storeCaret(this);"> </textarea>
</div>
<div style="float: left;margin-left: 5px">
<input type="button"  value="Add Gap"  onclick="insertText();">
</div>
```

Please help me

Comment: Where is `insertText()` code?

Comment: Textareas can't contain images, only text. Maybe you need a WYSIWYG editor like http://ckeditor.com/ or http://www.tinymce.com/

Answer (score 1):

You can't insert images to textareas, because they are just capable of plain text. You could take a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_Editable